# Telerik RadGrid Does NOT select Row on LEFT CLICK when the cell value is a link

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

[image: The Grid Cell That Contains a Link]

I have custom columns in my **telerik rad grid for Asp.net** and some of those display links (A href='...').

*links work fine.*

the **PROBLEM** is that the grid **DOES NOT *SELECT* the ROW** of the cell that I clicked **ONLY when** I click on a cell that has a link (rather than plain text).

normally the grid **DOES SELECT** the row without any trouble when a user clicks on a **regular cell**.

this only happens when the cell content is a link.

any idea to get around this? please.

Code:

1 - The link behind the link (that goes into the grid cell)

```
<a href="#" onclick="commandManager(event, otherParameters);">Cotgrave</a>
```

2 - The code that's invoked.

```
    function commandManager(clickEventArgs, PARAMS)
    {
       $.each(PARAMS, function(key, value) { PARAMS[key].sourceItem = clickEventArgs.target; });  // NOT RELATED TO THIS ISSUE

       if(PARAMS.length == 1)
       {
          // NOT RELATED TO THIS ISSUE
       }
       else if(PARAMS.length>1)
       {
           showMenu(clickEventArgs, PARAMS);  <<- THIS IS WHERE OUR CASE FOLLOWS
       }
       else
       {
          // NOT RELATED TO THIS ISSUE
       }
    }
```

3 - Show menu function

```
    function showMenu(e, PARAMS) 
    {  
        if ((!e.relatedTarget) || (!$telerik.isDescendantOrSelf(contextMenu.get_element(), e.relatedTarget))) 
        {
            var contextMenu = $find("<%= RadContextMenu1.ClientID %>");

            contextMenu.get_items().clear();
            for(i=0; i < PARAMS.length; i++)
            {
                var childItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuItem();
                childItem.set_text(PARAMS[i].title);
                childItem.PARAM=PARAMS[i];
                contextMenu.get_items().add(childItem);
            }

            contextMenu.show(e);
        }
    }
```

Grid Markup

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    Skin="Default" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" UseStaticHeaders="true" ScrollHeight="10px" />
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
        <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" OnRowClick="RowClicked" OnRowSelected="RowSelectionChanged" OnRowDeselected="RowSelectionChanged"></ClientEvents>
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView AllowPaging="true">
        <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" />
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**Please let me remind that this code "WORKS FINE" The only problem is that the grid doesnt SELECT the row when the cell content is a link.**

Comment: The whole code for grid generation is very complex and spread to suit business problem.
The problematic area is very straight forward. All it does it catching the onClick event and show the context menu.
The problem should be the event not getting propagated after the show context menu.


I added the code.

Comment: am I the only one who's had this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the markup of your grid I can't be certain but I can think of 2 potential solutions.

Firstly, I apologise if you've already tried this but you've not put your grid markup on the question, you need to ensure you have set the selecting set up correctly to allow row selection `<Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" UseClientSelectColumnOnly="false" />`.

See: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/select-a-row-in-radgrid-after-a-linkbutton-in-the-radgrid-is-clicked.aspx

Another potential way of doing this would be to use the RadGrid Client API to select the row, assuming that either the `clickEventArgs` or `PARAMS` attributes contain a unique datakeyvalue for you to compare by this could be done using the set_selected function on the item.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. btw, I added the grid markup if you can please take a look again.